# Maximization question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to find the maximum value of the function $f(x,y)=(ax+by)^p+x^p$ subject to the constraint $x^p+y^p=1$. Here, $a,b$ and $p$ are constants with $a,b>0$ and $p>1$, and $x,y>0$. I have found the maximum in the special case $p=2$ and tried to use Lagrange multipliers in the general case but couldn't success. Any help?

Comment: What is $p$? Do you know $a$ and $b$ or are they unknowns? Is the problem concave? If you know all the values and the problem is concave, I recommend just using a numerical solver like CVX.

Comment: The constants a and b are unknowns. What do you mean by a"concave problem" and "CVX"? Thank you.